# Showing that Bezier curve length is less than its control polygon

Tags: bezier-curve

This is a homework and pardon me for the huge gap of my Mathematics knowledge. After thinking and referencing for a few days I came up with something like following, appreciate help to comment whether this is already correct:

By observing the following, it shows that the length of a Bezier curve converges to 1/n of its polygon's length

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. But you made two mistakes:

(1) In the second line, the control points of the derivative curve are $n\|\Delta C_i\|$, not $\|\Delta C_i\|$.

(2) In going from the second to the third line, you assumed that the norm of a sum of vectors is equal to the sum of their norms. This isn't true, in general. However the norm of the sum is *less than or equal to* the sum of the norms.

With those two changes, you have what you want.

Your conclusion that the arclength is $\tfrac1n$ times the polygon length is obviously false. Think about what this means geometrically, for $n=2$ or $n=3$.